# VB.net Unable to load data with Windows API into ComboBox

Tags: windows, vb.net, api, combobox

I'm trying to fasten up the loading of one form, which populates several combobox with a big amount of data. I did my best stopping the UI while loading ecc shredding the loading time from 20s to 13s, but still the only bottleneck remaining is loading data into ComboBox which takes about 3-4s each. I did research on the internet and found that using Windows API you can fasten it up a lot more. So I did the code:

```
Private Const CB_ERR As Integer = -1
Private Const CB_ADDSTRING As Integer = &H143
Private Const CB_SETITEMDATA As Integer = &H151

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, lParam As String) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)> lParam As Object) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Sub AddItem(cmb As ComboBox, Item As Object)
    Dim l As IntPtr
    Dim kryptoncmb As KryptonComboBox


    Try
        kryptoncmb = TryCast(cmb.Parent.Parent, KryptonComboBox)
        If kryptoncmb Is Nothing Then kryptoncmb = TryCast(cmb.Parent.Parent, KubaUtility.KryptonComboBox)

        If kryptoncmb IsNot Nothing Then
            l = SendMessage(kryptoncmb.Handle, CB_ADDSTRING, IntPtr.Zero, Item.ToString())
            SendMessage(kryptoncmb.Handle, CB_SETITEMDATA, l, Item)
        Else
            l = SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_ADDSTRING, IntPtr.Zero, Item.ToString())
            SendMessage(cmb.Handle, CB_SETITEMDATA, l, Item)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

My problem is that when it gets to CB_SETITEMDATA, it tries to load the item's data but instead it throws an Exception:

> No existing PInvoke conversion for the value passed to the Object type parameter.

The object I try to pass is a custom class but it's plain simple, just bunch of properties.

Comment: While you **may** trim a very small fraction of a millisecond by using your code that sends the **same messages** as the ComboBox Class does, you are not gaining much.  You will be better served by heeding the advice given in the documentation's Remarks Section for [ComboBox.BeginUpdate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The real problem is populating CBOs `with a big amount of data`.  Especially since the data is a class, use a DataSource.  I did a quick test and showing 5k, 7.5k and 10k items in 3 different CBOs, takes less than 3 secs; and that is much much mroe than the average user can consume.  The 3 secs includes time to create the item collections.  Controls make horrible variables including collections